# Android app doesn't recognize changes made in XCode

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to build a project in cocos2d-x, but when I modify a class in XCode, the iOS version changes, but when I run the app in my Android device by Eclipse, the app doesn't change.
How can I fix this?
I just did the setup as said in the cocos-2d X v3.0 and runned build_native.py.

Comment: delete the app from device, see what happens when you deploy again

Comment: Try clean the Eclipse project

Comment: Thanks, I just needed to run the .py file in android.proj.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cocos2d-x 3.0 eclipse projects do not rebuild the native code. You need to run the build_native.py script from the command line each time you change C++ code. Then you can load it onto your android device (through eclipse if you want).